# How do I skip next if condition is not met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to loop back to get another input if the input does not match, but it ends the program from there.

I have tried this code:

```
 print ('What would you like to purchase?')
    buy = input('(Enter what you would like to purchase?)') 
    if buy not in items_for_sale_today2: 
        print ('Please try again')
    else:
        purchase = input('How many {buy} would you like to purchase?'.format(buy = self.buy))
```

as well as:

```
 print ('What would you like to purchase?')
    buy = input('(Enter what you would like to purchase?)') 
    while buy not in items_for_sale_today2: 
        print ('Please try again')
    else:
        purchase = input('How many {buy} would you like to purchase?'.format(buy = self.buy))
```

but while function will keep printing 'Please try again' instead of looping back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case 2 you need to take input from the user again

```
print ('What would you like to purchase?')
buy = input('(Enter what you would like to purchase?)') 
while buy not in items_for_sale_today2: 
    print ('Please try again')
    buy = input('(Enter what you would like to purchase?)') 
else:
    purchase = input('How many {buy} would you like to purchase?'.format(buy = self.buy))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python the `while ... else ...` works like this:

```py
while statement:
    # keep do something until statement is not `True`
else:
    # do something after while loop finished
```

The code you expect should be:

```py
print ('What would you like to purchase?')

while True:
    buy = input('(What you would like to purchase?)') 
    if buy not in items_for_sale_today2: 
        print ('Please try again')
    else:
        break

purchase = input('How many {buy} would you like to purchase?'.format(buy = self.buy))
```